# How to direct page using javascript (or jQuery) with button tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have code html like this:

```
<td colspan="7" class="cart_but">
    <button class="continue"><span>icon</span>Continue shopping</button>
    <button class="update"><span>icon</span>Update your cart</button>
</td>
```

And jQuery code to direct page, but when click in button there is nothing happen:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('button.continue').click(function() {
            //window.location = "abc";
            window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com";
        });

        $('button.update').click(function() {
               //window.location = "<?php echo base_url('checkout'); ?>";
        });
    });
</script>
```

Please help me!

Comment: Why aren't you using a regular link in the first place?

Comment: The code looks fine, but you can use an onclick event instead of jQuery.

Comment: Maybe you're clicking the "Update your cart"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the button type to button - it's submit by default which submits the page regardless of your click event handler :)

```
<td colspan="7" class="cart_but">
    <button type="button" class="continue"><span>icon</span>Continue shopping</button>
    <button type="button" class="update"><span>icon</span>Update your cart</button>
</td>
```

Comment: It only does that if the button is inside a form, and this could be the issue, but there is no indication that the OP has placed the buttons inside a form ?

Comment: I think the tick next to the code is an indication, but thanks for clarifying that. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try this one.....

```
$('button selector').click(function(){
   document.location.href='the_link_to_go_to.html';
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Your javascript code is right. I think have some js conflict or some error, turn your firebug console and make sure you have no error here.

Comment: I'll do it now. Welcome to VN.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all. Maybe there is something error when I include this script from other file to master page. I copy it direct to master page and it ran.